# WP7 Phone Contact Images Uri

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am developing a windows phone 7 App where I need to display the contact Images in a ListBox with Image control & display list of selected Images by the user on another UI page and maintain it in IsolatedStorage to display the same list later,i know Its not possible to save the Images directly into IsolatedStorage , so I want to store the Image Uri as string in IsolatedStorage and reference those images later when I need to display them.

Comment: I am storing the Image Stream and converting it each time i need to display it But i have a huge Contact list

Comment: Elaborate a little more, I dont understand what you have actually done so far. Best way is to create a Class which will hold contact information and the URI to your Image, then just use an ObservableCollection<Class> and bind it to your controls, use the selectionchanged event handler to handle the users selection to which you can then work on moving to the next page etc